# How to display second checkbox name aligned

Tags: html, checkbox

```html
<html>
  <table width="45%"><tr><td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="mahesh" value="mahesh">Mahesh</td>
    <td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="mahesh" value="mahesh">Mahesh kunenaddsfsdfasdfasdfa</td></tr>
    <tr><td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="mahesh" value="mahesh">Mahesh</td>
    <td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="mahesh" value="mahesh">Mahesh kunenaddsfsdfasdfasdfa</td></tr>
    </table></html>
```

I want second check box name is to large, it should align properly below the name .
It should start from the name not form checkbox

Comment: Since you're using a table for layout (not recommended), just split the cells so that the checkbox is in one cell and the text on another.

Comment: You can refer this link : http://www.outsidethebracket.com/align-radio-buttons-checkboxes-labels/. See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ywg632c3/3/

Answer (score 0):

you can use additional element - label, like this:

HTML:

```
<table width="45%">
 <tr>
     <td>
         <input type="checkbox"  name="mahesh1" value="mahesh"/>Mahesh
     </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="maesh1" name="mahesh1" value="mahesh"/>
        <label for="maesh1"> Mahesh kunenaddsfsdfasdfasdfa</label>
     </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="mahesh2" value="mahesh"/>Mahesh
     </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="maesh2" name="mahesh2" value="mahesh"/>
        <label for="maesh2"> Mahesh kunenaddsfsdfasdfasdfa</label>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

css:

```
label {
    display: block;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ywg632c3/2/